# Is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]$ a UFD or not?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]$ a UFD or not? I feel like there should be some easy example showing that it is not, but I can not think of one.

Comment: Common trick is to check $(1+ \sqrt{-7})(1-\sqrt{-7})$

Answer (score 5):

$2^3=(1+ \sqrt{-7})(1-\sqrt{-7})$

$2$ is irreducible since $2=ab \implies N(a)=2$, but there are no elements of norm $2$ since $x^2 + 7y^2 = 2$ has no solution because $y=0$ is the only choice for integral solutions to this equation.

$2$ is not prime since $2\mid (1+ \sqrt{-7})(1-\sqrt{-7})$ but $2\nmid 1 \pm \sqrt{-7}$.

Comment: On the other hand, the integers of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-7}\,)$ do form a UFD.

Comment: Yes it is a PID! But this is too deep for this question I guess. I don't know a simple way to show that avoiding the Finiteness Theorem.

Comment: You just have to believe the Minkowski bound, which seems to tell me that I don’t need to check any ideals at all for principalness.

Comment: Yes I meant that Theorem! My English is quite bad sorry! :)

Comment: And of course that theorem is hardly elementary…