# $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]$ is UFD?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory

I read on Wiki that according to Heegner,  $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]$ is a UFD. But I read in a book that $2$ is an irreducible but not a prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]$ . Doesn't that mean it's not a UFD ? So what is wrong here ?

Comment: Yes. My bad. Online by the phone so I don't see the mistakes. Thank u

Comment: irreducible and prime are different things.

Comment: Yeah. But in UFD they are the same, right?

Comment: They do, I just searched that on stack

Comment: That's why it confuses me so much. I don't know what is wrong here

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1628624/is-mathbbz-sqrt-7-a-ufd-or-not?rq=1) answers your specific question, and [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70976/why-is-mathbbz-sqrt-n-n-ge-3-not-a-ufd) answers it for $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}]$ for $n\geq 3$.

Comment: So wikipedia about ufd is wrong?

Comment: The ring of integers of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$ is a UFD (that is part of the easy direction of Heegner's theorem). The catch is that the ring of integers of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt n)$ is equal to $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt n]$ if and only if $n\not\equiv1\pmod 4$. When $n\equiv1\pmod4$, then the ring of integers is
$$\Bbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{n}}2].$$ So the Wikipedia result that you saw means that the ring $\Bbb{Z}[(1+\sqrt{-7})/2]$ is a UFD.

Answer (score 4):

$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]$ is not UFD.Because $\mathbb1+\sqrt{-7}$ is irreducible element over $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]$ but not a prime .
(note:In integral domain primes are irreducible but in UFD prime implies irreducible and irreducible implies prime)

Answer (score 2):

from Gauss's method of periods,

$$ \sin( 2 \pi / 7 ) + \sin ( 4 \pi / 7 ) - \sin ( \pi / 7)  = (1/2) \sqrt 7$$
$$ \cos( 2 \pi / 7 ) + \cos ( 4 \pi / 7 ) - \cos ( \pi / 7)  = - 1/2 $$

I just like this.

If $t \neq 1$ is a 7th root of unity, $t^7 = 1,$ then
$$ x = t + t^2 + t^4 $$ is a root of
$$ x^2 + x + 2. $$
Easy enough to confirm, using
$$ t^6 + t^5 + t^4 + t^3 + t^2 + t + 1 = 0. $$
I wrote the bits with sine and cosine using $t = e^{2 \pi i / 7}.$ Note that
$t^4 = e^{8 \pi i / 7} = -e^{ \pi i / 7}$ because $e^{i \pi } = -1.$

[image]